# Cannot use master template in Flask error handler

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, jinja2

I can create an error handler in Flask which uses a Jinja2 template, but when I use a master template in that template, I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
INFO     2014-10-21 11:41:40,453 module.py:659] default: "GET /a HTTP/1.1" 500 291
```

Here is my handler code:

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
   return render_template('404.html'), 404
```

The template:

```
{% extends "master.html" %}
{% block body %}

404

{% endblock %}
```

I am using AppEngine Launcher for testing.

Comment: Can you show us the `master.html` if it's not too big?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have some sort of variable in `master.html` that is provider for other pages but not for the error handling page. Make sure if you are using any variables to check if the variable exist first before trying to access their properties.

Comment: Thanks. It turns it was because I was using request.endpoint to generate a canonical url.